# messed up kernel after amdgpu uninstall Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: boot, drivers, kernel, initramfs, amdgpu

I need help solving this issue thanks for your time!

I installed amdgpu (amdgpu-pro-21.30-1290604-ubuntu-20.04.tar.xz from amd.com website) a while ago and it was working fine on my Ubuntu 21.10. Then things broke after a gcc update (regular ubuntu update) and it couldn't compile anymore. Since then any updates to the linux kernel failed. Well they seemed to work but I couldn't boot anymore. During boot it stopped with a black screen.

I uninstalled amdgpu with the included command 'amdgpu-install --uninstall' and reinstalled the kernel but it did not change anything. I installed it again, got error message that it couldn't compile), no change. Then i removed it again, no change.
I reinstalled mesa packages, xserver, kernel including headers etc. But nothing changed, keep getting a black screen during boot.
I did a fresh install of ubuntu on a different partition just to copy the kernel (/boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-28-generic) from there to my /boot/. With that kernel file everything works fine, boot up is normal.
But as soon as a kernel is installed or update-initramfs is invoked i get the problem back again and I'm once again stuck on a black screen on boot.
I also tried installing older kernels and removing the new ones, it happened on every kernel I tried.

Error i get from update-initramfs:

```
cp: cannot stat '/lib/firmware/updates/amdgpu': No such file or directory
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/vangogh_gpu_info.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_ta.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_sos.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_rlc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_mec2.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_mec.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_sdma.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_vcn.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_smc.bin for module amdgpu
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/nvme0n1p2
```

I noticed that the malformed kernel (/boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-28-generic) file is larger than the one i copied from the fresh install. Don't know if that matters.
I never really used update-initramfs before but i looked in the config files under /etc/ and couldn't find anything suspicious.

My graphics card is a AMD navi 22 card, radeon 6700xt.
If i would have known that the driver from amd.com doesn't give any benefits over the driver included in the kernel for a regular user anyway, I would have never installed it in the first place. But now i need to get out of this mess. Please help

Comment: Reinstall ubuntu. That is the simplest way to fix it.

Comment: i was hoping there was an easier solution. reinstalling everything is so much work

Comment: While rebooting, can you use an older kernel from the grub menu? Does that kernel fix the issue?

Comment: for a while it worked with the older kernels. In my attempts to fix the problem that I originally only had with the newest kernel they were rebuilt by update-initramfs and then didn't work anymore.